# counterwithin problems with table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, chngcntr

I would like to use the option counterwithin to get my numbering as I, I.1., I.2, .., II, II.1, II.2,...

I use the following minimal script

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is part 1}
\chapter{This is I.1}
\part{This is part 2}
\chapter{This is II.1}
\end{document}
```

This does what I want, but in the table of content, for some reason, there is not enough space between the numbers and the chapter names. As the roman numbers get longer, the numbers and text even overlap.
[image: in table of contenn, spacing between number and text is not correct]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tocloft` and change the `numwidth`:

```
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
```

Change `2em` to whatever you desire.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is part 1}
\chapter{This is I.1}
\part{This is part 2}
\chapter{This is II.1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can do the same for `part`, `sec` `subsec`, `subsubsec` `para` and `subpara` in a similar fashion. Do

```
\setlength{\cftXnumwidth}{<dimension>}
```

Where `X` has to be replaced by `part` `sec` etc.

Comment: But I would use `\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}` so that chapter numbers are not prepended by part number.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** It is easy with KOMA-Script version 3.15 or newer. Just use the new command `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[counterwithin=part,tocnumwidth=2em]{chapter}
```

Note that the package `chngcntr` is not needed.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    counterwithin=part,
    tocnumwidth=2.5em
  ]{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is part 1}
\chapter{This is I.1}
\part{This is part 2}
\chapter{This is II.1}
\end{document}
```

---

You can use the package [`tocstyle`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/tocstyle.pdf) which is part of the KOMA-Script-bundle.

```
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tocstyle} 
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is part 1}
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\part{This is part 2}
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

You have to run the code several times to get:

[image]

Or you can use the option `toc=flat`:

```
\documentclass[openany,toc=flat]{scrbook}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\counterwithin{chapter}{part}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{This is part 1}
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\part{This is part 2}
\blinddocument\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Run twice to get

[image]