# How to automatically reset counter for appendix for a custom TOC in koma-script?

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, appendices

I would like to use a custom TOC declared by the `\DeclareNewTOC` command. Unfortunately the counter created with it does not resets itself upon the appendix.

While the counter within figure gets reset and the `\Alph{<counter>}` representation is being used. It does not get applied on the custom TOC which I declared.

I have already searched for solutions and read the koma documentation about the `\DeclareNewTOC` command but could not find anything. I found the `tocentrystyle` option key but couldn't make it to work. I mostly came across questions the other way around that they want to remove the reset etc.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=listing,
    types=listings,
    float,
    name=Listing,
    listname={List of Listings}
]{lol}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\listoffigures
\listoflistings

\mainmatter

\appendix

\chapter{Figures}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Listings}

\begin{listing}
\caption{This is an example}
\end{listing}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

The output is

**List of Figures**

```
A.1 Example figure
```

**List of Listings**

```
1. This is an example
```

---

I would like to have:

**List of Listings**

```
B.1 This is an example
```

---

**Edit (from the answer of gusbrs):**
using the option `counterwithin=chapter` inside the DeclareNewTOC or outside produces the correct numbering, however it does not update the padding between the number and the toc text as seen in this picture:

[image: List of Listings in appendix]

---

**Edit 2:**
This answer: [counterwithin problems with table of content](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181237/counterwithin-problems-with-table-of-content)
Helped me to find the options:

```
tocentrynumwidth=2em,
tocentryindent=2em
```

But currently `tocentryindent` does not match the default indent of List of Figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the indent and the number width for listing entries should be the same as for figure entries, use options `tocentryindent:=figure` and `tocentrynumwidth:=figure`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=listing,
    types=listings,
    float,
    name=Listing,
    listname={List of Listings},
    counterwithin=chapter,% <- added
    tocentryindent:=figure,% <- added
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure% <- added
]{lol}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\listoffigures
\listoflistings
\mainmatter
\appendix
\chapter{Figures}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Listings}
\begin{listing}
\caption{This is an example}
\end{listing}
\end{document}
```

[image]